# 23.04 Upgrade - no more deep sleep

Tags: suspend, idle

Since upgrading to 23.04 I've noticed that my laptop no longer enters deep sleep (suspend to RAM / S0i3). One of the reasons I switched from Tumbleweed back to Ubuntu was that I had issues getting S0ix sleep states to work, but when I installed Ubuntu 22.10 it worked out of the box.

Now when I put my laptop to sleep the battery will just barely last overnight, whereas prior to the upgrade it would last at least several days. Can anyone suggest where I should start trying to diagnose what's gone wrong?

Comment: maybe related for me with kubuntu: i was on kubunt 22.10 and the normal sleep-mode worked. - 
with the upgrade to 23.04 the laptop tries to go to sleep - but hangs in some form of login-screen - with display on. → so it is visible it does not sleep.

Comment: Does your laptop actually enter sleep mode? Mine does - the LED for awake/active turns off (there are 2 LEDs on the laptop, one for power and the other for awake/active). But it doesn't appear to reach deep sleep, as the battery still runs down pretty quickly.

S0ix is still relatively new and seems to introduce a lot of issues. What is your hardware? Mine is an 11th Gen Intel Core i7.

Comment: it does not reach sleep mode... i think it *kind of crashes* before it really is off.. my hw is [ASUS ZenBook Pro Duo UX581GV (github repro)](https://github.com/s-light/ASUS-ZenBook-Pro-Duo-UX581GV/) with a [Intel Core i9-9980HK](https://www.asus.com/laptops/for-home/zenbook/zenbook-pro-duo-ux581/techspec/) - my main interests is also in how to debug this / where to begin...

Comment: I seem to be having a similar issue on kubuntu running on a dell xps-13. Worked OK on kde NEON but doesn't seem to deep sleep on kubuntu as, like you, battery doesn't last the night any more. It does appear to be asleep though (no lights on anywhere).

Comment: Same issue here, since the upgrade from 22.10, I lost the deep sleep and the battery doesn't last the night. I a using a Dell XPS 15.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue when set the laptop to sleep using Kubuntu 23.04 and the sleep option in the menu. I did not find a solution to this yet, but a workaround. The laptop goes to sleep when with `pm-suspend`. This however does not lock the session. So I use this command:

```bash
sudo echo; qdbus org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver /ScreenSaver Lock; sudo pm-suspend
```

Not user friendly, but works.